# C# WPF Нужно что то вроде TextBox содержащий в себе ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Пните в нужную сторону пожалуйста, от количества перерытой информации уже голова начинает болеть, видимо не могу правильно сформулировать вопрос и поэтому не знаю где искать. Работаю с DataGrid, нужен столбец со строками в которые можно вводить текст (тот же TextBox), и снизу должен выпать список с наиболее подходящими под описание item'ами (тот же ComboBox). К примеру имеется некий условный список item'ов для ComboBox, (саморез 3.5х50, саморез 3.5х51, болт 8х55) Я ввожу в строку "саморез" и снизу выпадает список с любыми ближайшими совпадениями скажем item'ов на 5 (образно) после чего можно выбрать любой вариант и он занесется в строку. В DataGrid есть столбец DataGridTextColumn и DataGridComboBoxColumn как бы мне их правильно совместить чтобы получить вышеописанный результат? Или возможно есть другой способ реализации?

Comment: [Autocomplete combobox for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27963022/312041)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что вам следует переопределить `Template` у ячейки. Сделать это можно вот так:

```
         <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="True"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
```

**UPD**

И вот `ComboBox` можете настроить по примеру, который указал в комментариях  *tym32167*

Comment: Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос на как я могу обратиться к этому ComboBox из кода через DataGrid? Кстати Ваше свойство IsTextSearchEnabled="True" особо ничего не поменяло а вот IsEditable="True" дало нужный результат (по крайней мере визуальный) но возможно это не то. У меня возникли проблемы с заполнением ComboBox из-за того что не могу обратиться к нему в коде, поэтому наверняка сказать не могу, подскажите пожалуйста как обратиться к ComboBox из кода?

Comment: Это был глупый вопрос... Конечно же привести sender к ComboBox в обработчике события. Спасибо всем кто помог.